# How to draw a circle in Pygame with floating point radius?

Tags: python, pygame

So I need to draw a circle in Pygame with a floating point radius.
This is a brief idea of what I am trying to do.

```
pygame.draw.cricle(surface,(255,0,0),(15,15),13.41234)
```

This is the error that I get.

```
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: you could try int(radius), or round(radius). I think Pygame works with numbers of pixels so it wants an integer.
try: pygame.draw.circle(surface,(255,0,0),(15,15),int(13.41234))

Comment: I thought of that but I am trying to increase the radius of the circle in small increments, so if I use int(), the difference would not be seen since int(10.9) = 10 and int(10.1) = 10

Comment: Use `int(round(...))` instead of `int(...)` which truncates its argument. pygame is based on SDL, whose built-in drawing functions require integer coordinates / dimensions in order to support low-end systems.

Comment: that is true @oceandye, but the difference will not be visible before the size of the circle increase by at least one pixel, compared to the previous circle (the screen is not able to show fraction of pixels). Anti-aliasing can give the impression of a size increase smaller than a pixel, but i dont think pygame support this by now?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thanks I think that would work.

Comment: @KrisR89 I agree but given that diameter is 2r when you increase enough times the change to the area of the circle becomes quite drastic even if you increase by 1.

Comment: @oceandye rounding the radius is more intuitive than int, but it does not smooth the circles increase. "round" will result in 2.51 all the way to 3.49 to become 3 (an interval of size close to 1) as "int" between 3.0 and 3.99 becomes 3 (also an interval of size close to 1), hence equally discrete but computationally more efficient to only use int.

Comment: The units for the radius is `pixels`, they are not sub-divisible - there's no such thing as "half a pixel".  You must convert the radius to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

if you wants to use float in the radius you can drow an ellipse.
like this:

```
x = 10.123 #flote
y = 11.123 #flote

radius = 13.41234 #flote

pygame.draw.ellipse(surface, (255,0,0), (x, y, radius, radius))
```